# Computing the pullback of a 1-form

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let a holomorphic map $F : \mathbb{C}_{\infty} \to \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ be defined by the formula $w = z^N$ for some integer $N \geq 2$, where we use $z$ as an affine coordinate in the domain and $w$ as an affine coordinate in the range. Compute the pullback $F^{\ast}(dw)$ of the form $(1/w)dw$. Compute the orders of $F^{\ast}(dw)$ at all of its zeroes and poles.

My computation is as follows. $$F^{\ast}(dw) = dF^{\ast}(w) = dz^N = Nz^{N-1} = \frac{N}{w}dw.$$

I'm not sure of this is correct however.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's unclear whether you're computing $F^{*}(dw)$ or $F^{*}(dw/w)$;
2. Assuming you're computing $F^{*}(dw)$ (as stated), the second-to-last term is missing the factor "$dz$";
3. If you replace $w$ and $dw$ in the rightmost expression by $z$ and $dz$, respectively, that's $F^{*}(dw/w)$.

In short, computing pullbacks of one-forms is just like the method of substitution in elementary calculus.